# Image is not staying inside the box

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a fitness site and I wanted to have a sponsor section.
I saw this code that you see down, and it was fitting my website style.
I tried to fix it, but I just started to learn CSS, so I'm not good at it.
It's good but the images that I put in the box are sticking out of the box.

How can I change that the images stay inside the gray box?

```css
.sponsors {
  width: 999px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #999;
}

.sponsors span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
}

.sponsors a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 96px;
  width: 11%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

a.one {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300") no-repeat 0 0;
}

a.two {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300") no-repeat 0 0;
}

a.three {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300") no-repeat 0 0;
}

a.four {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300") no-repeat 0 0;
}

a.five {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300") no-repeat 0 0;
}

a.six {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300") no-repeat 0 0;
}

a.seven {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="sponsors">
        <span>Sponsors:</span>

        <a class="one" href=""></a>
        <a class="two" href=""></a>
        <a class="three" href=""></a>
        <a class="four" href=""></a>
        <a class="five" href=""></a>
        <a class="six" href=""></a>
        <a class="seven" href=""></a>
    </div>
```

Example:
[image: Example of Sponsor Section]

Comment: You should be using `<ul>` with an outer `<li>` for each `<a>` as it represents a list.

Comment: Inside which box you want your image?? Grey Box?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, the grey box

Comment: Just remove `float: left` from `.sponsor a`. It will be in the grey box, and exactly how you want it's not understandable with such vague sentence and no example image.

Comment: I added an example image and changed the question. Is it good now? I'm new, so please correct me if I am being too not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
display: block
```

to

```
display: inline-block
```

in your .sponsors class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at your .sponsor style with

```
padding: 50px;
margin: 15px auto;
```

Adjust the padding and margin properly to fit the images inside the div.

Comment: That's ok but it will be a very huge box and I don't want that.